# Number of group homomorphism from {$1, \omega, \omega^2$} to $S_{3}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ denote the group {$1, \omega, \omega^2$} under multiplication where $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity. How many group homomorphism are
there from $G$ to $S_{3}$, the permutation group over $3$ elements? From the concept number of normal subgroup given the possible homomorphism, I find only trivial homomorphism. Is this answer correct?

Comment: I thought $S_3$ has $6$ elements.

Comment: How many homomorphisms from $A_3$ to $S_3$ are there? Can you chain a sequence of homomorphisms $\{1, \omega, \omega^2 \} \to A_3 \to S_3$ to get any of the kind you're looking for, that are nontrivial?

Comment: That answer is not correct, no.  But sending everything to $e$ *is* one of the homomorphisms, so you've made a good start. Once you decide where $\omega$ goes, everything else is determined, so the largest possible answer is $6$. Now work out the actual answer...

Comment: order of $f(\omega)$ is either 1 or 3. So the possible homomorphism is 2.

Comment: @John Hughes is that above answer correct.

Comment: You're getting closer (in fact, I don't think you can get any closer without having it right!). As mentioned above, $f(\omega)$ determines $f$ completely, and you're right that the order of $f(\omega)$ is $1$ or $3$. But if we decide that the order of $f(\omega)$ should be $3$, then that leaves ...

Comment: that leaves odd permutation @pjs36

Comment: sorry, order three elements in $S_{3}$ are two.So the number of homomorphism is exactly 3.

Comment: is that above answer correct. @pjs36

Comment: Yep! You might want to compose your thoughts, and add an answer to your own question, now that you have all the ingredients