# How many group homomorphism are there from $A_3$ to $S_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How many group  homomorphism are there from $A_3$ to $S_3$?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2279225/476275) is possible duplicate  answer. I was reading it but could not understand anything.

My attempt:  $A_3\cong\Bbb  Z_3$. Both  have same order and the subgroups of $S_3$ are $\{0\}$ and $S_3$. By using the first theorem of isomorphism I get:

For $\{0\}$, $\Bbb Z_3/\{0\} = \Bbb Z_3$. Now the number of order in $\Bbb Z_3$ is $\varphi(3) = 2$.

For $\{S_3\}$, $\Bbb Z_3/S_3  =\Bbb Z_2$, now the number of order in $\Bbb Z_2$ is $\varphi (2)=1$.

So the number of group homorphisms from $A_3$ to $S_3$ is  $\varphi(2) + \varphi(3) = 2+1 =3. $

Is my answer is correct or not?

Please verify and tell me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a homomorphism from $Z_n$ to a group $G$, is given by $a\mapsto g^a$ where $g\in G$ and $g^n=e$. The number of these homomorphisms is
thus the number of solutions to $g^n=e$.

In $S_3$ there are three permutations whose cube is the identity.

Comment: +1 for ur answer,,,@ Lord Shark the unknown,,,can u tell me  how can i show in S3 there are three permutations whose cube is the identity?

Comment: @lomberlego You could write down all six elements of $S_3$.

Comment: @ Lord shark the unknown ..i have write {0},(12),(23),(13),(123) and (132)....now how can i show ?